# $W$ is a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ be a proper subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$

I am trying to prove that there exists scalars $a_1,...,a_m \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $v=(b_1,...,b_m) \in W$, $\sum a_ib_i = 0$.

I am also given the following information: Let $U$ be a subspace of $V$. For $f \in Hom(V,\mathbb{R})$, there exists $f|_U \in Hom(U, \mathbb{R})$. But I don't really know how to use this information in order to prove the affirmation given before.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative:

Presumably you are looking for $a \neq 0$ otherwise it is trivial.

Let $w_1,...,w_p$ be an orthonormal basis for $W$ and choose $a \notin W$.

Let $a'= a-\sum_k (w_k^T a) w_k$. It is easy to verify thet $w_k^T a' = 0$ for all $k$ and hence $b^T a = 0$ for all $b \in W$.